# How to add parameters to a Future for Mysql/Php Post Request?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use a future in Flutter/dart to insert a user's name, email, and URL to a php/mysql database. Is there any way to add parameters to this future so that PostSocialData() can be called from another page with the user name, email, and URL as parameters?
Here's what I tried:

```
Future<void> PostSocialData() async {

 String currentname;
 String currentemail;
 String currentavatar;

 PostSocialData({
   this.currentname,
   this.currentemail,
   this.currentavatar,
 });

  final userinfo = "http://example.com/postSocialUser.php?currentname=" 
   + currentname + 
   "&currentemail=" 
   + currentemail + 
   "&currentvatar=" 
   + currentavatar;

  final response = await get(userinfo);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response);
  } else {
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully post social data.');    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this code was intended to be a function or class. If you treat it as a function you could do the following

```
Future<void> PostSocialData(String name, String email, String avatar) async {
  final url = "http://example.com/postSocialUser.php?currentname=$name&currentemail=$email&currentvatar=$avatar";

  final response = await get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200)
    print(response);
  else 
    throw Exception('We were not able to successfully post social data.');    
}
```

Having this function you could call it by doing the following `await PostSocialData( "George", "george@gmail.com", "avatar" )`.

Also I would prefer to use camel case for naming functions ( `postSocialData` instead of `PostSocialData` ) and pascal case for naming classes.

I hope this helps you out,
Cheers